# Xcode 3 wont allow me to Install Xcode toolset

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

So I attempted at giving Xcode 4 a swing, after uninstalled XCode 3, and it failed me.With all the shortcuts out of place i didn't feel at home. So i uninstalled XCode 4, and began installing Xcode 3 once again. but this time. I am no longer allowed to download the Xcode Toolset.!

http://tinypic.com/r/29z242d/7

At first i assumed that the Xcode toolset would someone works it way into the instillation and it would all work out. but after installing this more that 3x on my computer I cannot seem to FIND XCODE at ALL! nor can i find iOS simulator or any other software. What do i have to do inorder to fix this?

I think this is happening because I inappropriately uninstalled Xcode 3 the first time, I used an application called App Zapper rather than running the -sudeo command...

Comment: I found out why it was't allowing me to download the Xcode toolset. The reason is that I was running OSX Lion and Lion Demands that you not downgrade your Xcode 4 to Xcode 3. But at the same time if you have Xcode 3 you can continue using it... Basically. If you cannot download the Xcode3 toolset and your running OSX Lion, its because you will no longer be able to.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Xcode 3 on Lion using the following method:

- Mount the Xcode 3.2.6 DMG
- Open Terminal
- Enter the commands:

  ```
  export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1
  open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"
  ```

Use at your own risk as Xcode 3 is not supported by Apple on OSX Lion.

If you are installing alongside Xcode 4, make sure to install into a different directory (create this in Finder first), and then you can untick all the boxes apart from the Essentials and it'll run just fine.

Source: http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads-up: on Mountain Lion and Mavericks (and quite possibly on other versions as well, but I only "tested" this two...) this causes a kernel panic at startup, so I would advise against installing Xcode 3 on them.

If you already did that, and need some help, [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5668268) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90288/mac-crash-after-installing-xcode) are some information.